# Is it possible to upgrade original iMac (1998) memory (RAM) to above 256 MB?

Tags: hardware, memory, apple, imac-g3

I am looking into buying myself an original iMac, as I want to mess with the older system a little bit.

Is it even remotely possible to change the RAM in the system to being over 256 MB? I am willing to do it even if it means changing out other parts to allow it to be possible.

(I asked this question at the Ask Different Stack Exchange, but I was referred to here for better help).

Comment: Just so you know, cross-posting is generally frowned upon. For some reason, people seem to be eager to suggest it to new users.

Comment: Get a slightly newer iMac.  My 450 MHz machine had dvd and could hold 1GB RAM.

Answer (score 5):

It would appear so. [This page](http://lowendmac.com/1998/original-imac-rev-a/) indicates that it may be possible to go up to 768MB.

You might have some work ahead trying to find those obsolete RAM modules, though...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is certainly possible. Bondi iMac (233 MHz) takes two SO-DIMM memories,
of the PC100 type, one of which must be low-profile (circa one inch high)
while the other may be high-profile (two inches).

Apple only tested this
machine with the available modules at time of manufacture, which included
256M high-profile and 128M low-profile, so the official recommendation
for maximum memory was 384 MB.  After a few years, though, low-profile
SODIMMs were available so that (with non-Apple modules) the early iMac
machines could take two 256MB modules, for a total of 512MB.

There were variants in later years, and some similar-looking
iMacs could take more memory, of PC133, but the original Bondi
233MHz iMac models required the organization variants that matched
PC100.

Typical memory offerings distinguished (and charged extra) for the
low-profile 256M variant modules [archived memory advertisement](https://web.archive.org/web/20060318194308/http://eshop.macsales.com/Catalog_Page.cfm?Parent=1382&Title=iMac%20G3%20144%20Pin%20SO-DIMM%20Memory%20Upgrades&Template=1)